# Nested list object does not support indexing

Tags: python, list, object, indexing

I have a nested list, named env, created in the constructor and another method to populate an element of the grid defined as below:

```
class Environment(object):
    def __init__(self,rowCount,columnCount):
        env = [[ None for i in range(columnCount)] for j in range(rowCount) ] 
        return env       

    def addElement(self, row, column):
        self[row][column] = 0
```

Later in the code I create an instance of Environment by running:

```
myEnv = createEnvironment(6,6)
```

Then I want to add an element to the environment by running:

```
myEnv.addElement(2,2)
```

So what I expected to happen was that I would receive a new Environment object as a 6x6 grid with a 0 in position 2,2 of the grid.  But that did not work.

I have two errors:

1. I am unable to return anything other than None from the **init** method.
2. The main issue us when trying to execute `addElement(2, 2)` I get this error:

   `"TypeError: 'Environment' object does not support indexing.`

I looked at the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods but was unable to get them working over a multidimensional list.  Is there a better data structure I should be using to create a grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't replace the object with `__init__`. You could subclass `list` and do something in `__new__`, probably, but that would be massive overkill, the better option is just to wrap the list:

```
class Environment(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self.env = [[None for column in range(columns)] for row in range(rows) ] 

    def addElement(self, row, column):
        self.env[row][column] = 0
```

Note that it's a little odd you claim to be calling `myEnv = createEnvironment(6,6)` - using a function rather than the constructor is a little odd.

If you really want your object to act like the list, you can of course provide a load of extra wrapper functions like `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`. E.g:

```
def __getitem__(self, row, column):
    return self.env[row][column]
```

Which would allow you to do `some_environment[5, 6]`, for example. (You may rather return the column, that depends on your system and what works best for you).